# How do I query sibling nodes from XML in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have some XML stored in a **settings** column in **my_table** in PostgreSQL.  The XML is similar to this:

```
<Dictionary>
  <ExportValues>
    <ReplacementSet>
      <type>TEST_CODE</type>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>A1</Input>
        <Output>One</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>A2</Input>
        <Output>Two</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>A3</Input>
        <Output>Three</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
    </ReplacementSet>
    <ReplacementSet>
      <type>TEST_TYPE</type>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>MTL</Input>
        <Output>Metal</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>LQD</Input>
        <Output>Liquid</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
      <ReplacementPair>
        <Input>SLD</Input>
        <Output>Solid</Output>
      </ReplacementPair>
    </ReplacementSet>
  </ExportValues>
</Dictionary>
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
type, Input, Output
TEST_CODE, A1, One
TEST_CODE, A2, Two
TEST_CODE, A3, Three
TEST_TYPE, MTL, Metal
TEST_TYPE, LQD, Liquid
TEST_TYPE, SLD, Solid
```

I am able to get the values from the **type** node with the following SQL:

```
select xxx.*
  from xmltable('/Dictionary/ExportValues/ReplacementSet'
                passing xml((select settings
                               from my_table
                              limit 1))
                columns replacement_value_type text path 'type') xxx
```

And I am able to get the values from the **Input** and **Output** nodes with the following SQL:

```
select xxx.*
  from xmltable('/Dictionary/ExportValues/ReplacementSet/ReplacementPair'
                passing xml((select settings
                               from web_service
                              limit 1))
                columns our_value text path 'OurValue',
                        their_value text path 'TheirValue') xxx
```

However, I can't figure out how to select the value from the respective **type** nodes with all of the **Input** and **Output** node values within the **ReplacementSet** nodes.

Everything that I have tried has either errored out, included the **type** values, but nulls for **Input** and **Output**, or nulls for the **type** and values for the **Input** and **Output** nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem, but you have to specify XPath for "type" column explicitly:

```
select x.* 
  from my_table, 
       xmltable('/Dictionary/ExportValues/ReplacementSet/ReplacementPair'
                passing settings 
                columns
                  type text path '../type', 
                  input text path 'Input', 
                  output text path 'Output') x;

+-----------+-------+--------+
|   type    | input | output |
+-----------+-------+--------+
| TEST_CODE | A1    | One    |
| TEST_CODE | A2    | Two    |
| TEST_CODE | A3    | Three  |
| TEST_TYPE | MTL   | Metal  |
| TEST_TYPE | LQD   | Liquid |
| TEST_TYPE | SLD   | Solid  |
+-----------+-------+--------+
(6 rows)
```